# Automatically hide row/change colour once end date passed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table of students for attendance which enrolls in my course... in the table course end date is also mentioned

Table Code is Given Below:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th><?php echo "Student Name"; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo "Joining Date"; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo "Batch End Date"; ?></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

Table Body Code

```
<tbody>
    <td><?php echo $value['firstname'] . " " . $value['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['admission_date']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $value['course_end_date']; ?></td>
</tbody>
```

The Body Data is In Variable Which Picks Data from another List and Showed Content... Look Like in the Front View

```
<tbody>
    <td>Kapil</td>
    <td>09/15/2019</td> 
    <td>10/20/2019</td>
</tbody>
```

The Above code is using For Student Attendence

**What I am looking for is:**

1. student detail or row doesn't show once his Batch End Date Passed.
2. and the row changes color on the last day of the Batch End Date.

Comment: `Table Body Code` - so, you have only cells in table body, with no rows? doesn't look like valid HTML at all .. why use a table for this if you only have a single student

Comment: table data change

Comment: purple monkey dishwasher - what do you mean? you still have 3 TD's as children of `TBODY` ... no rows at all -  what is the point of using a table for non-tabular data

Comment: The Body Data is In Variable Which Picks Data from another List and Showed Content... Look Like in the Front View

<tbody>
    <td>Kapil</td>
    <td>09/15/2019</td> 
    <td>10/20/2019</td>
</tbody>

Comment: yes, and I keep saying that is invalid HTML, and it makes no sense to even use a table for a single line of data - doesn't matter how many times you repeat your HTML, it's going to be invalid every time